# Update Tkinter canvas in mainloop()

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am trying to create a simple Bubble Sort Visualization in Tkinter but I have no idea how to update canvas/refresh.

```
from tkinter import *
import random
height, width = 350,600
randomLines = []
master = Tk()
w = Canvas(master,width=width,height=height)
w.pack()

def drawRandomLines():
    w.delete("all")
    for i in range(width):
        w.create_line(i,0,i,randomLines[i])

def bubbleSort():
    for passnum in range(len(randomLines)-1,0,-1):
        for i in range(passnum):
            if randomLines[i]>randomLines[i+1]:
                temp = randomLines[i]
                randomLines[i] = randomLines[i+1]
                randomLines[i+1] = temp

for i in range(width):
    rnd = random.randint(0,width)
    randomLines.append(rnd)
drawRandomLines()
bubbleSort()
mainloop()
```

If I use drawRandomLines() inside bubbleSort() loop It will hold the window and wont show the canvas till it is sorted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to want to use `after()` to manager an updating loop that wont affect the mainloop. By using `after()` we can create a visual update over time. We will need a tracking variable to manage the index on the loop and a global statement for the tracker.

Example:

```
from tkinter import *
import random
height, width = 350, 600
randomLines = []
master = Tk()
tracker = 0
w = Canvas(master, width=width, height=height)
w.pack()

def drawRandomLines():
    global tracker
    if tracker <= width:
        w.create_line(tracker, 0, tracker, randomLines[tracker])
        tracker += 1
        master.after(10, drawRandomLines)

def bubbleSort():
    for passnum in range(len(randomLines)-1, 0, -1):
        for i in range(passnum):
            if randomLines[i] > randomLines[i+1]:
                temp = randomLines[i]
                randomLines[i] = randomLines[i+1]
                randomLines[i+1] = temp

for i in range(width):
    rnd = random.randint(0, width)
    randomLines.append(rnd)
drawRandomLines()
bubbleSort()
mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Tkinter will not update window until the queue of important things are done. So you will have to force it if you want updates every iteration. Try this:

```
def drawRandomLines():
    w.delete("all")
    for i in range(width):
        w.create_line(i,0,i,randomLines[i])
    w.update()   # Force canvas update
```

Comment: I think you might have meant to indent `w.update()` at the same level as `w.create_line()` instead of after the loop is completed. They way you have it now it is not going to change anything visually.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `after()` to replace the outer `for` loop in `bubbleSort()` and call `drawRandomLines()` inside `bubbleSort()`:

```
from tkinter import *
import random

height, width = 350, 600
thickness = 5

# create the random lines
randomLines = [random.randint(1, height-1) for i in range(0, width, thickness)]

master = Tk()
w = Canvas(master, width=width, height=height)
w.pack()

def drawRandomLines():
    w.delete("all")
    for i in range(len(randomLines)):
        x = i * thickness
        # use bars for more clearly presentation
        w.create_rectangle(x, height, x+thickness, height-randomLines[i], fill='red')

def bubbleSort(passnum):
    for i in range(passnum):
        if randomLines[i] > randomLines[i+1]:
            randomLines[i], randomLines[i+1] = randomLines[i+1], randomLines[i]
    drawRandomLines()
    if passnum > 0:
        master.after(20, bubbleSort, passnum-1)
    else:
        w.create_text(50, 50, text='Done!', font=('Arial', 24))

drawRandomLines() # show initial order of lines
bubbleSort(len(randomLines)-1)

master.mainloop()
```